# output of web service to convert SQL to SQLite

Tags: android, sql-server, web-services, sqlite, ksoap2

i'm trying to build an android app which sends login details to SOAP 1.1 web service(C#) and gets employee details. i'm using ksoap2 v2.3 lib and developing for gingerbread version v2.3 of android. presently web service is returning plain data table. suggest me with the form of data the web service should return and which form i should choose to retrieve the data and save it to my local SQLite db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its better to use ArrayList. i have tried it. :)